# Where do I get the jersey-guice package?

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I would like to use Jersey and Guice together and I have found [this tutorial](http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-guice-ified-jersey-in-embedded.html), and a reference to jersey-juice [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1865).

However, I'm not using Maven. I downloaded the main jersey package, but it does not include jersey-juice.  Where do I get that package?  All the links I've found are to a Java.net page that indicates that the file isn't found.

Comment: You can still download the JAR from the maven repositories directly: http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the confusing link. You can find jersey-guice on maven central - this link has all the versions - just click on the jar link next to the version you want:
http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.sun.jersey.contribs%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jersey-guice%22